# Why is there a SyntaxError Python

Tags: python, variables, input

I wrote this code snippet:

```python
lowestNumber = int(input("\nWhat would you like your lowest number to be?"))
highestNumber = int(input("What would you like your highest number to be?"))

number = random.randint(lowestNumber, highestNumber)

tries = 0
while tries < 10:
    guess = int(input(f'\nEnter a number between', lowestNumber))
    if guess == number:
        print("You guessed correctly! The number was", number)
        break
    elif guess < number:
        print("Too low!")
    elif guess > number:
        print("Too high!")
    tries += 1
```

`SyntaxError: bad input on line 22 in main.py`.

Line 22 was `guess = int(input(f'\nEnter a number between', lowestNumber))`.

I searched it up on google and got nothing, I pasted it into OpenAI's code fixing and it also didn't help.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Read [ask] first.

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote

```python
guess = int(input(f'\nEnter a number between', lowestNumber))
```

it passed both the string and `lowestNumber` into the input function. However, you probably wanted to write something like `Enter a number between (lowestNumber) and (highestNumber)`. To do this, you would have to write

```python
guess = int(input(f'\nEnter a number between {lowestNumber} and {highestNumber}. '))
```

In my example, it passes in one object, the string, which contains `lowestNumber` and `highestNumber` in it. In your example, it passes in two objects, the string and `lowestNumber`.

The formatting you did in the input functions works in print statements, so the print statements are correct, but the input function is not.